# Import text file into python and separate each character into one cell grid in table python

Tags: python, tkinter, datatable, drawimage

I have difficulty creating a function for a Tkinter button. Button and tkinter program has already been created. Import each character from text file into its own cell in the table.

*example.txt*:

```
hello t
code th
```

I want it to print import text and print into this :

[image: expected printed output]

To be able to access each cell individually to change the text from expected printed output to :

[image: changed output]

Then,  Change one cell grid in table.

Comment: You would need something like tkinter to make this work

Comment: So you want to do [GUI programming in Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+gui+programming&oq=python+gui+programming&aqs=chrome.0.0j46l2j0l6j46.3024j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Better post what you have tried so far and state what problem you came across.